# Converting from VB6 to VB.NET, Recordset

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, vb6

I have an old program I'm looking to convert from VB6 to VB.NET

Here's the code:

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path & "\TestDB.mdb" & "; Persist Security Info=False;"
cnn.Open
rs.Open "SELECT Addresses.*, Accounts.[Login Status], * FROM Accounts INNER JOIN Addresses ON Accounts.AccountID = Addresses.AccountID WHERE (((Accounts.[Login Status])=Yes))", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

rs.AbsolutePosition = 1

lblFirstName.Caption = rs![Addresses.First Name]
lblLastName.Caption = rs![Addresses.Last Name]
lblAddress.Caption = rs![Address]
lblPSPR.Caption = rs![Parish/State/Province/Region]
lblZipCode.Caption = rs![Zip Code]
lblCountry.Caption = rs![Country]
lblTelephoneNumber.Caption = rs![Addresses.Telephone Number]
lblCellNumber.Caption = rs![Addresses.Cell Number]
lblAddressID.Caption = rs![AddressID]
cnn.Close
```

Now the code I here passes the sql result to the labels mentioned above and by changing the rs.AbosolutePosition i can either display the 1st row, 2nd row, 3rd row etc. Now my question is how to i accomplish this in VB.NET ?

Comment: http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson04

Comment: If you know what it does in `vb6` this can be easily translated into `.net`. What have you tried?

Comment: If you have a VS2008 installed, it can apparently convert vb6 code to vb.net. From there you can open the VS2008 code in a more recent version and upgrade it there.

Comment: I also found this vb converter - I haven't tried it, so can' vouch for it. http://www.vbto.net/

Comment: @Jeremy - The link you posted is not relevant because DataReader objects are forward-only so they don't support absolute positioning.

Comment: I think I would open an OledbDataReader, create a table object, load the data into the table, then just move the data from the first row of the table to the new labels' text attributes.  This way, you could get to any record (absolute positioning?).  It should work fine.  The above is opened as read-only, so there shouldn't be any need to update.

Comment: Are you aware that you can add a COM reference to your .NET project, e.g. "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library", and continue to use ADODB.* objects as before?